# Unable to remove components from a managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-field, partner-communities

I just developed a package in salesforce and uploaded it. The uploaded package is of managed type. I need to modify the definitions of a custom object component in the managed package which has become a pain point now. Salesforce does not allow to make changes in the managed object. While looking for the alternate options,

I just came to know these things

1. Partner Apps(ISV) have a special privilege to make some changes in
   the managed object and also to update the managed package

   Ref: [are custom fields deletable from a managed package?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/are-custom-fields-deletable-from-a-managed-package)
2. Partner account holders can resolve this by submitting a case from
   the same with the details of package and organization

   Ref: [This developer doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm)

Apart from these two solutions, Is there any way to enable component modification in a managed package?

This is really cumbersome for someone who is developing an app and needs to publish it in the market place within a targeted time. Need Assistance

Comment: FYI. I do have a partner account and I just want to upgrade the package which is already released

Comment: No other option. In fact it is there to protect your clients. When you delete a managed package component there are all sorts of things you need to consider from your client's perspective. You will have to go through the steps to get the deletion of components enabled and then it is something you really need to read and understand the consequences.

Comment: will Another Version of package work ?

Comment: @Eric I need to modify the custom object definition in the package(upgraded version) which is not yet installed by anyone but a managed one(Not listed as public in marketplace). And the component I want to modify is not in the previous versions of the package. Still no way to do it?

Comment: @Magesh - Please read the guide on managed package components. Once they are uploaded into a package you cannot change certain things about the objects.